Non-linear parameter optimization using Python
I have a model that generates the curve represented by the red squares the data represented by the black circles.
The model curve (red squares) depends on some parameters to fitting. Is there any Python function suitable for estimating this kind of non-linear regression problem? I tested "least_squares" and "curved_fit" and didn't get good results (i.e., the red squares should represent an average behavior of the black circles as in the attached figure)
For this type of problem, should the objective function return the sum of the residuals or a vector of the residuals?
For "least_squares", I used the objective function below:
def objective_function1(params,x,y):
    param1, param2 = params
    y_calculated = model_func(x, param1, param2)
    residuals = np.sqrt((np.array(y) - np.array(y_calculated))**2)
    return residuals

For "curved_fit", I used the objective function below:
def objective_function1(params,x,y):
    param1, param2 = params
    y_calculated = model_func(x, param1, param2)
    residuals = np.sqrt((np.array(y) - np.array(y_calculated))**2)
    return np.sum(residuals)

Notes: "model_func" is returning the expected values ​​when I use "param1" and "param2", "y" and "y_calculated" are size consistent and I'm getting the correct values ​​of the vectors "x" and "y".
Many thanks.


What exactly do you mean by not getting good results?

I understood your point, my reference was confusing. I'm sorry. For example, apparently the curve of the red squares should represent the average of the black circles (as in the image). However, the optimized parameters that I am obtaining through the "least_squares" and "curved_fit" functions in Python do not generate a red curve that represents an average of the black points.

Without seeing your code or anything that you did, we can't provide any insight. My guess would be is that the function basis you chose doesn't capture the "best" result you want.

@SeanRoberson I improved my question. Apparently the parameters are not being optimized in a way that captures the data trend in black circles. This is the point. I don't know if there is any different strategy for optimizing parameters in a problem of this complexity.

I haven’t done a lot of curve fitting yet, but you should consider doing data preprocessing before actually running the least square model. Why not use a filter sort of thing and loop it through all ‘grids’ you define somehow and reduce the amount of data points in each grid to a more uniform amount? The fitting result should be considerably more accurate with less data points at the bottom, though you have to make the grids for scanning fine enough. I have no idea if it would be anything ML people would actually do in practice as I’m no expert, but having that many data points at the bottom would definitely weight out other loss yielded by data points on top.

In fact, the points at the bottom are values ​​< 0 and in theory are the most important for the model. I tried applying a weight factor by multiplying each residue which would be exp(-value). Thus, the values ​​at the bottom would have more weight. But unfortunately it still didn't work out. I don't know if it could be something related to the algorithm, if a global optimization strategy is needed, if the objective function is falling into a local minimum.

I’m sorry but I still couldn’t really understand the situation. May you provide the current fitting result and perhaps the full code, nature of data set and a more specific objective? Since you just mentioned values < 0 and I have no idea what’s going on. Btw I don’t see a reason you do sqrt() for least square errors as it basically just adds unnecessary complexity to back propagation. TLDR, I really hope I could get more information from you! Thanks
